# 他のファイルからViewControllerのUILabelを変更したい

Tags: swift, ios

## 実現したいこと・問題点

Swift初心者です。
表題の通り、他の.swiftファイルから直接、ViewController.swiftに関連付けされているUILabelのテキストを変更することはできないかと思い、後述のようなコードを書きました。

storyboard上にSliderとLabelを配置し、Sliderを変更した際の処理をLowPass.swift内に記述するというようにしています。

このまま実行するとビルドはされるのですが、Sliderの値を変更するとエラーが出てしまいます。
エラーの原因は、LowPass.swiftのvcにnilが入ってしまっていることだとは分かるのですが、改善策が分かりません。

どなたかご教授頂けますでしょうか。

## 該当のソースコード

```
//ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

    // LowPass.swiftのインスタンス生成
    let lowPass = LowPass()


    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
        slider.maximumValue = Float(150)
        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.setValue(lowPass.R, animated: true)
        slider.addTarget(lowPass, action: #selector(lowPass.RChange(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    
        label.text = String(lowPass.R)
    
    }


}
```

---

```
//LowPass.swift
import UIKit

class LowPass: NSObject {

    weak var vc: ViewController!

    var R: Float = 30.0

    @objc func RChange(sender: UISlider){
        R = Float(sender.value)
        vc.label.text = String(R)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、`LowPass.swift`は

```
weak var vc: ViewController!
```

を、`vc`に「クラス外からアクセス出来る変数だよ」と明示的に宣言するため、

```
public weak var vc: ViewController!
```

としておいたほうがいいでしょう。
これで、`nil`だった変数`vc`の中にクラス外から値を代入できるようになります

次に、`ViewController.swift`の中で、

```
let lowPass = LowPass()
```

としているところをを

```
let lowPass = LowPass()
lowPass.vc = self
```

として、`LowPass`クラスのインスタンスを生成した後に一行追加します。
これで、インスタンス変数`lowPass`の中で宣言したメンバー変数`vc`
の中に`ViewController`の`self`つまりクラスのインスタンス自身を保持できるようになります。

これで、`vc`が`LowPass`クラスの初期化が終わるまでは`nil`ですが、コンストラクター(=`init`)が終了すると、`ViewController.swift`の`lowPass.vc = self`が実行され、`nil`ではなくなりますので、それ以降は`vc`が`nil`で落ちることはなくなると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！インスタンスの保持ということを考えていませんでした。勉強していきます。